# failing to pass argument to puppet apply with facts

Tags: scripting, puppet, facter

I am trying to pass a facter argument to `puppet apply`. Here's what I tried:

```
export FACTER_command="start"
puppet apply site.pp $FACTER_command
```

and in my code I have:

```
exec { 'some_exec':
  command => '/bin/bash -c "/some/path/to/scripts.sh -t some_arg $::command"',
```

...

I get this message error:

```
Error: '/bin/bash -c "/some/path/to/scripts.sh -t some_arg $::command"' returned 1 instead of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Standard/Exec[some_exec]/returns: change from 'notrun' to ['0'] failed: '/some/path/to/scripts.sh -t some_arg $::command"' returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

Does anyone have any idea about this?

UPDATE

```
class standard{

        $param_test="/some/path/to/scripts.sh -t some_arg ${::command}"
        file{'kick_servers':
                ensure => 'file',
                path => '/some/path/to/scripts.sh',
                owner => 'some_user,
                group => 'some_user',
                mode => '0755',
                notify => Exec['some_exec']
        }

        exec { 'some_exec':
               command => '/bin/bash -c ${param_test}',
               cwd => "$home_user_dir",
               timeout     => 1800
        }
}

node default {
    include standard
}
```

And I get this error

```
Error: '/bin/bash -c $param_test' returned 2 instead of one of [0]
Error: /Stage[main]/Standard/Exec[some_exec]/returns: change from 'notrun' to ['0'] failed: '/bin/bash -c $param_test' returned 2 instead of one of [0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You have at least two issues you need to fix there:

1/

The immediate cause of your problem is you have enclosed `$::command` inside single quotes, telling Puppet that you mean the literal string `$::command`, when you actually want the value of the fact there.

2/

You should not be passing `$FACTER_command` as an argument to `puppet apply`; you only need to export it as an environment variable (which you already did).

So:

Change `puppet apply` to:

```
puppet apply site.pp
```

Change your exec to:

```
exec { 'some_exec':
  command => "/bin/bash -c '/some/path/to/scripts.sh -t some_arg ${::command}'",
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you, in fact I had in deed that in mind and I also tried it with the same error except that a 2 as error status : `returned 2 instead of one of [0]`

Comment: I can only answer the question as you have asked it, maybe update the question to show everything you tried and all relevant details?

Comment: I updated the code of my manifest post and indicated the error I get

Comment: @user1611830 You haven't fixed both of the issues that he identified and gave you solutuions to.

Comment: @user1611830 You have made the same mistake again where you have `command => '/bin/bash -c ${param_test}',`. Those should be double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I think you are going to have to literally write out exactly what to do.